# Tailwind React dynamic class names does not get built

Tags: tailwind-css

### Problem

I want to reuse my React component with different colors. I want to pass color to the child node as a prop and then use it in className as **part** of Tailwind class.

Here follows example code to illustrate the issue:

App.jsx:

```js
import Box from "./Box";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row">
      <Box color={"red-500"} />
      <Box color={"blue-500"} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Box.jsx:

```js
export default function Box({color}) {
    return <div className={`bg-${color} w-10 h-10 m-2`}></div>
}
```

The result should look something like this:

[image: Preview of desired result]

Instead the color is not applied - I get white boxes. Tailwind classes `bg-red-500` and `bg-blue-500` are not generated.

### Possible solutions

#### 1. Full class names

If I pass full Tailwind class names to child and not try to create a class name by sticking 2 stings together, it works.

```js
<Box color={"red-500"} /> => <Box color={"bg-red-500"} />
...
return <div className={`$bg-{color} w-10 h-10 m-2`}></div> => return <div className={`${color} w-10 h-10 m-2`}></div>
```

However, this is not ideal solution because I would like to use the same color with different classes like `bg-red-500`, `text-red-500`, `hover:text-red-500` etc. So I would prefer reduced code duplication.

#### 2. Use safelist

Full class names can be added to safelist in tailwind config to make sure they are always generated.

```
module.exports = {
...js
  safelist: [
    "bg-red-500",
    "text-red-500",
    "hover:text-red-500",
  ],
...
};
```

Form Tailwind [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes):

> Safelisting is a last-resort, and should only be used in situations where it’s impossible to scan certain content for class names. These situations are rare, and you should almost never need this feature.

I am not a fan of using last-resort features and I would still need to manage a lot of classes in safelist for a single color.

## Question

Is there a better way to dynamically use Tailwind classes? What is the recommended solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still involves some duplication, but I would suggest organizing your classNames inside a config object and then passing in only the color name to the `Box` component.

```js
const boxStyles = {
  red: 'bg-red-500 text-red-500 hover:text-red-500',
  blue: 'bg-blue-500 text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-500',
}

export default function Box({ color }) {
  return <div className={`${boxStyles[color]} w-10 h-10 m-2`}></div>
}

// in App.js
...
<Box color='red' />
```